# SQL: Reassign id based on schedule

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the Bus schedule table

```
StopID BusID Start Stop
1      1     0400  0500
2      1     0800  0900
3      2     0600  0700
4      3     0700  0830
```

I want to be able to change all instances of say BusID=2 to another BusId that is not overlapping with it's current schedule. I'm fairly new to SQL but could I get any pointers on writing a procedure to do so?

I want to update the table so it would end up as

```
StopID BusID Start Stop
1      1     0400  0500
2      1     0800  0900
3      1     0600  0700
4      3     0700  0830
```

for all instances of bus 2.

Comment: so it means if it's overlapped with its current schedule, it will be deleted?

Comment: Please show us what the output looks like.

Comment: Sorry for being slightlly unclear. I was hoping to update the table so the busid2 entry would end up as StopID:3 BusID:1 Start:0600 Stop:0700.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_to_date(<string>,"%h%i")` function with `not exists` :

```
set @myBus_ID = 2;

select *
  from tab t
 where not exists (select 0 
                     from tab 
                    where Bus_ID = @myBus_ID
                      and str_to_date(start, "%h%i")<=str_to_date(t.stop, "%h%i") 
                      and str_to_date(stop, "%h%i")>=str_to_date(t.start, "%h%i"))
```

the query returns `Bus_ID = 1` for your current case.

> or replace `str_to_date(<string>,"%h%i")` with
>   `time_format(<string>,"%h%i")` as an alternative function.

to update your schedule, you can use :

```
set @myBus_ID = 2;

update tab t
join 
(
 select distinct Bus_ID
   from tab t
  where not exists (select 0 
                      from tab 
                     where Bus_ID=@myBus_ID 
                       and time_format(start, "%h%i")<=time_format(t.stop, "%h%i") 
                       and time_format(stop, "%h%i")>=time_format(t.start, "%h%i"))
) tt
  set t.Bus_ID=tt.Bus_ID
where t.Bus_ID=@myBus_ID;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41305cb5fd6f8ccf786e2fe16ff5df4e)</kbd>

Comment: I don't understand what advantage str_to_date affords in this instance

Comment: yes, this can also be handled without conversion, but I believe the right way to compare dates rather than strings, am I wrong ? @Strawberry

Comment: No, you're not wrong - I guess I just think it would be better to store the values as (an indexed) time data type.